# wrap scanned json with "translation" | i18n-scanner

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I use React with `react-i18next` and to generate the i18n json files I use `i18next-scanner`.

As I have seen, the `react-i18next` json files need the key `"translation":{...}` for everything else.

How can I add the `i18next-scanner` automatically?

EDIT:

i18n.js

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import de from './de/resource.json';
import en from './en/resource.json';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    lng: 'en',
    load: 'all',
    ns: false,
    resources: { de, en },
    react: { wait: true },
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
});

// eslint-disable-next-line
export const t = i18n;
```

This i how I need it to work:
src/i18n/en/resource.json

```
{
  "translation": {
    "component": {
```

This is how i18next-scanner cerates the files:
src/i18n/en/resource.json:

```
{
   "component": {
```

And what I need is either that `react-next` does not need this translation or `i18next-scanner` takes this into account.

Comment: It is not true, there is no need for this prefix in the json.

Comment: @felixmosh I will add the code. If I didn't have this `translation` key, it dose not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the fact that you are using **inline** resources, there is a need to prefix with "translations", you can do it in the usage.

```js
// i18n.js

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import de from './de/resource.json';
import en from './en/resource.json';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    lng: 'en',
    load: 'all',
    ns: ["translation"], // <-- specify the NS's exists
    defaultNS: "translation", // <-- what is the default namespace
    resources: { de: {translation: de}, en: {translation: en} }, // <-- this is the change
    react: { wait: true },
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
});

// eslint-disable-next-line
export const t = i18n;
```

This "translation" prefix is called **namespace** in i18next space. That means your translation files can be split into separate files.

**Pay attention**, when you are using inline resources, that means your bundle files will contain all of the translation when the user uses only one of the languages.
Check out [i18next-xhr-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend), which will fetch the user required language on runtime.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the repo here. Then you can also look at the i18next-scanner.js. Your fix is not pushed, but does not work locally.
And I'll be sure to check that out with the i18next-xhr-backing.

https://github.com/E-Edu/frontend/tree/feature/auto-parser-i18n
The i18n config is in `src/i18n/`
And the i18n-scanner is in the root dir

Comment: Ok, got my mistake, I've updated my answer, basically added the defaultNS & ns properties, (before that i called my NS `translations` in plural instead of `translation`)

Comment: Pay attention that you resources json should not have translations prefix (as it is generated using i18next-scanner)

Comment: thanks. that worked. I'd like to give an upvote too, but I only have 13 points...